# (headless server building android application) failed to find target with hash string 'android-22' in:

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

I am attempting to build Android applications on an Ubuntu server with **no graphical interface**.  The sdk is on a disk mounted in /mnt/data since the root directory doesn't have enough space for it.  I installed all of the packages for the Android SDK using the following command: ($ALLVERSIONS is just a string with 1,2,3,... 159 generated with a for loop, 159 is the max number in the listed installable items found with android list sdk --all)

```
android update sdk -u -a -t $ALLVERSIONS
```

I list the possible targets with:

```
android list sdk --all --extended
```

This shows the following targets being installed:

```
id: 27 or "android-22"
    Type: Platform
    Desc: Android SDK Platform 5.1.1
    Revision 2
...
----------
id: 30 or "android-19"
    Type: Platform
    Desc: Android SDK Platform 4.4.2
    Revision 4
```

However for some reason every application I try to build (using gradle or the gradle wrapper) I get an error such as the following:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find target android-19 : /mnt/data/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 28.949 secs
```

or:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-22' in: /mnt/data/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.414 secs
```

Thank you for the help.

edit: trying to set $ANDROID_HOME to the platforms directory instead of platform-tools resulted in the following

```
ubuntu@androidmonkey:~/working/TraceTester$ ls
app  build  build.gradle  gradle  gradle.properties  gradlew  gradlew.bat  settings.gradle  TraceTester.iml
ubuntu@androidmonkey:~/working/TraceTester$ ./gradlew assembleDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-22' in: /home/ubuntu/android-sdk-linux/platforms

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.607 secs
ubuntu@androidmonkey:~/working/TraceTester$ ls /home/ubuntu/android-sdk-linux/platforms
android-10  android-13  android-16  android-19  android-21  android-3  android-6  android-9
android-11  android-14  android-17  android-2   android-22  android-4  android-7
android-12  android-15  android-18  android-20  android-23  android-5  android-8
ubuntu@androidmonkey:~/working/TraceTester$
```

Comment: There's not supposed to be a directory with those names. `android-19` and `android-22` will be in `platforms`, not `platform-tools`.

Comment: So should my $ANDROID_HOME environment variable be set to the platforms directory then?  I tried setting it to the new value and still got an error, I have posted it in the original comment.

Comment: Ok it seems like I just misread the documentation, $ANDROID_HOME needs to point to the parent directory of platforms and platform-tools.

Comment: Correct. `ANDROID_HOME` is the SDK installation directory, where `platforms/`, `platform-tools/`, `extras/`, and various other directories reside.